# Google sign-in API without basic profile info

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am trying to simply get the Google sign-in button working on my website, but I am stuck at the following step:

[Getting profile information](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people)

As you can see, Google has taken an extremely straightforward task and made it impossible with contextless code snippets, and I am absolutely stuck. Right now, all I have done is put the following in the head of my HTML file:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="(I PUT MY CLIENT ID HERE ALREADY).apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

All I want to do is sign the user in WITHOUT requesting email address. My problem is the following:

- WHERE do I put the `gapi.load('auth2', function()...` code snippet? At the top level of my webpage's JavaScript file? In the body's `onload` function? In the `onSignIn` function? NONE of the above are working. I get an exception, or it says "gapi is not defined" or it says "auth2 is not defined" etc... And once that code snippet is in place, where do I put the `if (auth2.isSignedIn.get())` code snippet? You'd think the geniuses at google would think to include this incredibly simple, vital information in their tutorial. Incredibly frustrating.

Comment: You were right about terrible docs. Though.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the url a callback function to be run when the javascript gets loaded.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=googleLoaded" async defer></script>
```

So in your code you can do

```
function googleLoaded(){ 
  // The script is ready to use.
  // gapi.load('auth2', function()...
}
```

found here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Comment: Thank you for the help. Putting the callback in the url seems so... substandard. But that's what I'll try, since google gives no other choice (or has failed to elaborate any other choices).